# Load SQL Create DB file to Docker

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I am having trouble to load in my SQL File to create the schema and the associated tables, I have also tried to use the 'volumes' option in the compose file to copy the sql file into the 'docker-entrypoint-initdb.d' directory but that fails to so anything.

---

Table + Schema: https://pastebin.com/RTBBGZhn

MySQL Dump: https://pastebin.com/6ApQwt1F

---

Docker Compose File

```
version: '2'

services:
  melissabot:
    image: melissabot
    build: .
    ports:
      - 7000:7000
      - 7070:7070
    depends_on:
      - mysqlMelissa
    links:
      - mysqlMelissa:db

  mysqlMelissa:
    image: mysql
    build: ${PWD}/Docker/DB/
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      # - MYSQL_DATABASE=MelissaBot
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
     - 8080:80
    volumes:
     - /sessions
    links:
      - mysqlMelissa:db
```

---

Dockerfile

```
FROM mysql:5.6
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
# ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=MelissaBot
COPY setup.sh /mysql/setup.sh
COPY dump.sql /mysql/Melissa.sql
RUN chmod +x /mysql/setup.sh
RUN /mysql/setup.sh
```

---

setup.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
service mysql start
mysql -u root MelissaBot < /mysql/Melissa.sql
service mysql stop
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it wrongly. There is no init system inside docker. So you should not be using `server start/stop` inside a container. Look at the official image documentation always

https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql

> Initializing a fresh instance
>   When a container is started for the first time, a new database with the specified name will be created and initialized with the provided configuration variables. Furthermore, it will execute files with extensions .sh, .sql and .sql.gz that are found in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d. Files will be executed in alphabetical order. You can easily populate your mysql services by mounting a SQL dump into that directory and provide custom images with contributed data. SQL files will be imported by default to the database specified by the MYSQL_DATABASE variable.

So you can either copy your default dump files to `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` or mount them using a volume mount when running the container. So you chuck your `setup.sh` and change your Dockerfile to something like below

```
FROM mysql:5.6
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=MelissaBot
COPY dump.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

But I would rather prefer the approach of volume mounting it inside my compose file

```
  mysqlMelissa:
    image: mysql:5.6
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=MelissaBot
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - dump.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/dump.sql
```

Comment: Sorry should made it explicit, I have used the `volumes` section to move **just** the SQL file, but when I check phpmyadmin the DB is no where to be seen.

Comment: The you should check `docker-compose logs mysqlMelissa` to check what it shows. It would definitely show some error or why the dump is not loaded

Comment: I thought I had tried that, must of skipped past it when looking at the docs +rep